# C# command line app that shows an input box - how to suppress the dos box?

Tags: c#, console

I'm writing a quick C# console app to prompt a user for a shortcut name and then create a LNK file in a specified directory.

Is there a way to show *only* the inputbox and not the black console window?

Comment: convert into windows application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's so simple just change the output type from Console Application to Windows Application. This can be done under Project -> Properties -> Application in Visual Studio. this will run your application without `DOS` console box.

Answer (score 1):

It's not that difficult to create a simple windows forms application that would only have an input box and that would not open a console window.

Answer (score 0):

In the project properties, set the executable type to be "GUI" instead of "Console".  If you compile the application as a console executable, Windows will show a command prompt for the application, even if it does GUI things.  Compiling as a GUI executable will suppress the command prompt window.